# What is the difference between these NGINX's modules?

Tags: module, nginx

I'm reading the documentation, I found these NGINX's modules:

- [HttpLimitReqModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule)
- [HttpLimitZoneModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitZoneModule)

What are the differences? They are pretty similar to me, no?

Answer (score 2):

`HttpLimitReqModule` is supposed to limit the request rate (number of requests per given time), while `HttpLimitZoneModule` is used to limit the number of simultaneous connections.